# Vsiual Studio 2015 deleted all project folders following a forced shutdown

Tags: visual-studio-2015, delete-file

I thought I should report this unbelievable BUG in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Had a number of projects saved in the default *My Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects and Backup Files* folders. On one debug session for one of the projects, the application went into an infinite loop, so had to force a shutdown.

Then what Visual Studio 2015 did, was DELETE ALL PROJECT FILES IN ALL FOLDERS, so that they were COMPLETELY UNRECOVERABLE!!! Also nothing could be done using the "restore previous versions" utility. Thought I should report this DISASTROUS BUG to everyone out there.... and THANK YOU... MICROSOFT!

Does anybody out there have any ideas how to restore files for this disastrous type of situation?

Comment: Are you sure the projects haven't been hidden or moved elsewhere? Did you try search your computer for these?

Comment: Or that your application was doing some kind of "delete all files under a certain folder" thing, using the working directory or some other directory you're not expecting?